# browser history and wrong address

Tags: reactjs

I have a routing:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}> 
        <Route path='/' component={Main} >
            <Route path='/genres' component={Genres} />
            <Route path='/genres/:id' component={GridMovies} /> 
    </Route>
</Router>
```

**Main** component:

```
<div className="main-conteiner">

     <Genres />            
       {this.props.children}

</div>
```

**Genres** component do this:

```
let genres = this.state.genres;

        return (
            <div className="genres-list">
                {genres.map(function(key) {
                    return <Link to={"genres/" + key['id']} className='genre'>{key['name']}</Link>
                })}
            </div>
        )
```

I have list of genres here: [image]

Then i click some genre, i got adress:

```
http://localhost:8080/genres/28
```

Its good, that work. If i click again, i got this:

```
http://localhost:8080/genres/genres/28
```

Some clicks and i can got this:

```
http://localhost:8080/genres/genres/genres/genres/genres/genres/genres/genres/genres/genres/genres/genres/18
```

My server configuration:

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base public/ --history-api-fallback
```

Hash history doesn't work. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Link` isn't set properly. It should be:

```
<Link to={"/genres/" + key['id']} className='genre'>{key['name']}</Link>
```

because you want it to be relative to the root, not the current path.